# Why is rxjs not canceling my promise?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am using `rxjs` in my `angular` app.  I don't always get the data back in the order I want when multiple `REST` calls are made.

Controller:

```
constructor() {
    rx.Observable.fromPromise(this.getExpenses(toDate, fromDate))).subscribe(res => {
            that.setExpenses(res);
    }); 
}

getExpenses(toDate, fromDate) {
    return this.expenseService.getExpenses(fromDate, toDate);   
}

updateDate() {
    rx.Observable.fromPromise(this.getExpenses(toDate, fromDate))).subscribe(res => {
            that.setExpenses(res);
    });     
}
```

Service:

```
getExpenses: function(fromDate, toDateloadExtendedData) {
    return Restangular.all('expenses').getList({fromDate: fromDate, toDate: toDate});
},
```

In my `constructor`, I want to get the results for the current year, but sometimes the user will update the date before the call in the `constructor` returns.  I then have a race condition, because the user wants the `updateDate` info, not the `constructor` info.  How do I get back the most recently requested data?

Comment: Could your provide more context to this? All you have shown is a single promise resolution, how are you using this code? Where are multiple promises being generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have done nothing to "link" the two sequences, how can RxJs ever know they are related?

You need to create a single stream, then you can use [switch](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/switch.md) to observe the most recent request only:

```
constructor() {
    this._requests = new Rx.Subject();

    // listen to requests
    this._requests.switch().subscribe(res => this.setExpenses(res));

    // start the first request
    this._requests.onNext(this.getExpenses(toDate, fromDate));
}

updateDate() {
    // start a new request
    this._requests.onNext(this.getExpenses(toDate, fromDate));
}
```

Note that this won't actually *cancel* the previous requests.  It will just ignore any results they produce.  If you really want to *cancel* them, your expense service would need to provide an API for cancelling in-progress requests.

Comment: I posted a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151520/how-to-ignore-all-from-an-observable-if-the-other-observable-has-data-in-rxjs). Hope you can shed some insights.