# How to ignore all from an observable if the other observable has data in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have two observables, one receives data from the browser **localstorage** and the other is from the **database** through **WebAPI**.

1. I want to subscribe to them so if the observable from the **localstorage** has data, don't initiate the one to get the data from the **database**.
2. If the observable from the **localstorage** does not have any
   data, invoke the **ajax** call to get the data from the **WebAPI**.

In the following example, I should get only `20, 40, 60, 80, 100` because the first observable has data. The second observable did not run because the first observable started emitting data.

[image]

Comment: How many values do you expect to be emitted by the local storage observable? Presumably, only one; in which case the question is a dupe of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39200507/6680611

Comment: I want all the values in that observable as I mentioned in the question. They are ```20,40,60,80,100```.

Comment: Your marble diagram does not represent the question posed above it. In the diagram, both streams begin **at the same time** and you've stated that the bottom stream is to be ignored. Whereas, in the question above it you state that the ajax observable **is not to be initiated** if the localstorage observable has data. Also, you don't define what "has data" means. Does the localstorage observable complete? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: The marble diagram is just a guide to show that there are two streams. The second ajax observable/stream should not start if the first observable/stream has data. The localstorage observable can or can't have data. It is more like a local cached data. When the app starts there wont be any data. The data that the ajax observable brings in from the server will be written to the local storage. From the next time onwards the app will get the data from the local storage observable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local storage observable needs some way to signal that there is no data.  If it just "hangs" and never completes, then you might use a timer to complete it:

```
// Use .amb() instead of .race() if your rxjs version is old
const timer = Observable.timer(1000).ignoreElements();
const lsObservable2 = Observable.race(lsObservable, timer);
```

This will start a timer and if the local storage observable does not produce a value within 1s, it will end the stream.

If your local storage observable will complete on its own if there is no data, then you can use it as is:

```
const lsObservable2 = lsObservable;
```

At this point, we'd really like to use [defaultIfEmpty](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-defaultIfEmpty), because that has the semantics you want.  Unfortunately it only supports a scalar value for the default, when instead you want to yield a different observable stream.  So lets write our own version of `defaultIfEmpty` which produces a new stream using [Observable.defer](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer).  We use `defer` so that each time someone subscribes, we can create a new closure variable (`hasValue`) and monitor whether or not the source observable produces a value for this subscription

```
Observable.prototype.defaultObservableIfEmpty = function(defaultObservable) {
    const source = this;
    return Observable.defer(() => {
        let hasValue = false;
        // create a deferred observable that will evaluate to
        // defaultObservable if we have not seen any values, or
        // empty observable if we have seen any values.
        const next = Observable.defer(() => hasValue ? Observable.empty() : defaultObservable);

        // now use do() to set hasValue to true if we see a value from
        // the source observable
        const sourceSetsValue = source.do(v => hasValue = true);

        // now we can can just concat this sourceSetsValue
        // with out "next" observable.  When the first observable
        // finishes, it will subscribe to "next", which will then
        // either produce the defaultObservable or an empty observable
        return sourceSetsValue.concat(next);
    });
}
```

Next, let's assume you've setup your db Observable to not issue the ajax call until it is actually subscribed.  This is an important step. Again you can use something like `defer`:

```
const dbObservable = Observable.defer(() => makeDbCall());
```

Then we can use your new operator like so:

```
const data = lsObservable2.defaultObservableIfEmpty(dbObservable);
```

So your application code looks like this (once you've added the new operator to your library):

```
const timer = Observable.timer(1000).ignoreElements();
const lsObservable2 = Observable.race(lsObservable, timer);
const dbObservable = Observable.defer(() => makeDbCall());
const data = lsObservable2.defaultObservableIfEmpty(dbObservable);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use skipWhile and check for the data and return true or false.

```
observableObject.skipWhile((data)=> {
      if(data){
          return false;
      }
});
```

Comment: This will work with only one observable. There are two observables in the question.

Comment: can you elaborate.

Comment: You may look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190606/why-is-rxjs-not-canceling-my-promise). I think both these problems are trying to solve a similar problem. But in my problem, I want to cancel or don't initiate a promise/ajax call if the cache has already data.